# How to work with Keda using Azure pod identity

Tags: azure, keda, aad-pod-identity

I'm trying to use pod identity in conjunction with [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) to access some Azure resources, Azure Service Bus & Keyvaults to be precise.

I noticed the `aadpodbinding` should be set when deploying the operator according to [these instructions](https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/concepts/authentication/#azure-pod-identity). I am probably misinterpreting the instructions because the way I read it is that I need to have a single `aadpodbinding` ie. have some sort of cluster-wide "keda-identity"?

I wonder how I could utilize pod identity in my scenario: I want to have a separate identity for every solution running in my AKS cluster. These identities will provide the solutions with access to Azure resources and then I want to use those identities to provide the authentication as well for KEDA. I do not want a shared identity to access multiple resources on my subscription.

Surely this is possible and I am misinterpreting the instructions somehow (not being a native English speaker)?

Comment: Check the documentation of pod identity (https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity). you can create multiple `AzureIdentity` and related `AzureIdentityBinding`. Then `aadpodbinding` label need to match the selector of the `AzureIdentityBinding`.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I understand this part but is there a way to pass multiple different ```aadpodbinding``` to be used by the KEDA operator for better resource isolation between solutions?

Comment: Or if not, do you know how I could syntactically add multiple ```aadpodbinding``` to the deployment? I understand this latter question is more of a pod identity and doesn't have anything to do with KEDA.

Comment: Following the pod identity documentation (https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity#3-deploy-azureidentity) you should be able to map as many managed identities/service principal as you'd like.

Comment: Hmm I'm probably a bit slow here but I guess it is then so that I am interpreting this wrong:

"Azure AD Pod Identity will give access to containers with a defined label for aadpodidbinding. You can set this label on the KEDA operator deployment. This can be done for you during deployment with Helm with --set aadPodIdentity={your-label-name}."

The way I understand it is that the operator will be bound to a single label. I will have multiple, each solution will have a different one.

I would like to avoid having a keda-identity that is bound to every single solution.

Comment: Also, I understand that you can have n identities and bindings, but how would I syntactically add multiple to the deployment:

metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: $IDENTITY_NAME
    aadpodidbinding: $ANOTHER_IDENTITY

For example doing the above I still only get 1 binding for the deployment.

Comment: sorry i m not familiar with keda, could you create an identity just for keda ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add pod identity binding using the command:

```
helm install keda kedacore/keda --set podIdentity.activeDirectory.identity=app-autoscaler --namespace keda
```

But this didnt make my day to successfully scale the KEDA scaler using pod identity trigger auth

tried opening a new [query here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517746/keda-scaler-not-working-on-aks-with-trigger-authentication-using-pod-identity) to try to get it scaled using pod identity trigger