# KEDA Trigger Authentication with Azure Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-aks, keda

Does KEDA support azure service principal(client id and secret)? I read through the documentation but could not find an example. The documentation did mentioned service principal for key vault but my understanding is that the service principal here is to authenticate to key vault then read the secrets from there.

[image]

Comment: Hello Sandy, I hope I understood your question correctly. I haven't tried it personally, but I think it is possible in this way- First you can create your service principal with necessary permissions for the service you are integrating with suppose AKS. Store the client ID and secret of the Service Principal in a Kubernetes secret and then in your KEDA ScaledObject configuration, reference the Kubernetes secret for authentication.

Comment: @Arko, my usecase is to authenticate to eventhub with service principal. If I am reading your comment correctly, I can add service principal(clinetid and secrets) to keyvault then keda would read these service principals from keyvault to authenticate to eventhub? As per KEDA documentation eventhub authentication can be done via pod identity or connection string, thats what makes me confuse. There is no example of authentication to eventhub with service principals.

Answer (score 0):

KEDA supports Azure service principal authentication. You can use Azure service principal (client ID and secret) to authenticate to Azure Key Vault and read secrets from there. You can then use these secrets to authenticate to other Azure services, including KEDA. Once you have authenticated to Azure Key Vault, you can use the secrets to authenticate to KEDA. Here's an example of how to authenticate to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Azure service principal

To set up Azure service principal authentication for KEDA,
Create the Service Principal using CLI or portal and get the `appId` (client ID) and `password` (client secret) and `tenant`

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name arkokedaServicePrincipal
```

[image]
Assign the necessary permissions to the service principal for the Azure resource you intend to monitor with KEDA.

```
az role assignment create --assignee <appId> --role <role> --scope <scope>
```

Here replace `<appId>`, `<role>`, and `<scope>` with the values you recieved from the first step.

or if creating a fresh resource like AKS cluster then directly push it while creating the cluster

```
az aks create \ --resource-group myResourceGroup \ --name myAKSCluster \ --service-principal  <appId> \ --client-secret  <password>
```

[image]

Store Service Principal Credentials i.e. the service principal's `appId` and `password` in a Kubernetes secret. Replace `<client-id>` and `<client-secret>` with your values.

```
kubectl create secret generic my-keda-secret --from-literal=AzureClientID="de471dbf-XXX-XX-XX-XX" --from-literal=AzureClientSecret="XXX~L4HVPmZ-XX7Xzx" --from-literal=AzureServiceBusConnection="Endpoint=sb://kedacluster.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXX6wrr/CIc3iBQXXX+AXXXM="
```

[image]

Make sure you have already installed Keda on your system
helm install keda kedacore/keda --namespace 
[image]

Finally configure KEDA to use the Service Principal

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: my-scaled-object
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: productpage-v1
  triggers:
    - type: azure-servicebus
      metadata:
        queueName: kedaqueue
        connectionFromEnv: AzureServiceBusConnection
  authenticationRef:
    name: keda-trigger-auth-service-bus
```

Here replace the productpage-v1 with your own deployment which you want to scale with keda- and kedaqueue with your own service bus queue name
[image]

Create a `TriggerAuthentication` YAML  to accompany the `ScaledObject`, since you also need a `TriggerAuthentication` resource to refer to the secret holding the service principal's credentials.

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-service-bus
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: connection
      name: my-keda-secret
      key: AzureClientID
    - parameter: connection
      name: my-keda-secret
      key: AzureClientSecret
```

apply them with kubectl apply -f 
[image]

Now you can monitor Keda for autoscaling events-
`kubectl logs -f deployment/keda-operator -n <namespace>`

```
kubectl get deploy -w
```

[image]

Reference Documents:

- [Azure Key Vault developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide#authenticate-to-key-vault-in-code)
- [Use a service principal with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#other-considerations)
- [Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517746/keda-scaler-not-working-on-aks-with-trigger-authentication-using-pod-identity)
- [KEDA KV Secret](https://keda.sh/docs/2.12/authentication-providers/azure-key-vault/)
- [KEDA Authentication with example](https://keda.sh/docs/2.12/concepts/authentication/)

Comment: Thanks @Arco for sharing detailed steps. In this example you are configuring servicebus as trigger but your example using connection string from environment. Am I missing something?

Comment: In my usecase I am using eventhub as trigger but as per documentation eventhub authentication can be done via pod identity or connection string,"You can authenticate by using pod identity or connection string authentication."

Source: https://keda.sh/docs/2.12/scalers/azure-event-hub/#authentication-parameters

Comment: Yes, Sandy, you're right. KEDA supports both connection string authentication and pod identity for Azure services like Service Bus and Event Hubs. The example provided uses a connection string from a Kubernetes secret for simplicity. For your case with Event Hubs, you can indeed use pod identity for authentication, which is a more secure method recommended for production environments. The process involves setting up an Azure Identity and binding it to your Kubernetes deployment, which KEDA then uses to authenticate to Event Hubs. Let me see if I can find any reference using Event Hub for you.

Comment: Thanks @Arko. The AKS cluster I am working with does not have pod identity setup and I can only authenticate to eventhub with service principal, I can not request pod identity or connection string for eventhub. I am trying to figure out how I can make KEDA authenticate to eventhub with service principal.

Comment: @Sandy once check this [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/keda-eventhub-kafka-scaler-terraform/blob/master/README.md), here they are Autoscaling a Java application with KEDA using Azure Event Hubs. I am just trying my best to help you :-)